# Next.js SSG page not attaching events or running Javascript when accessed directly

Tags: next.js, netlify

I've got a next.js (11) site that generates a bunch of SSG pages. Everything works great when I enter the site through the homepage, which is static and navigate to the SSG page.

BUT, if I go directly to the SSG page, nothing works. Javascript doesn't run. Events aren't attached. No errors. Just... dead except for the static content.

Am I missing something about how Next.js works here? Is there a way to force these pages to function when accessed directly?

The site is running on Netlify. All of this works locally but not in production.

Answer (score 2):

The answer for posterity is that there's no reason it should act this way. It's a bug that results from minifying the Javascript on Netlify. Once I turned that off, everything behaved as expected.

Things I tried:

- SSR instead of SSG... but that breaks Netlify redirects and is slower.
- I also tried a trick I saw suggested to do a useEffect to set some unused key in state and force a rerender, but because Javascript was garfed, that didn't even fire.
- Dynamic loading of modules. Also didn't work right with the minification in place.
- Updates of all of my component modules-- including Next and the Netlify Next plugin.

Then, just by chance and desperation, I clicked off the post-processing minification button and everything started working again.